# Gehring lemma for fractional maximal functions

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis, elliptic-pde

Given a function $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the Gehring lemma states that if there exists $p>1$, a constant $C_0>1$ and a cube $Q \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that for almost every $x\in Q$, it holds
$$
\sup_{r>0} \left( \frac{1}{ r^n } \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p} \leq C_0 \sup_{r>0} \left( \frac{1}{r^n} \int_{B(x,r)} |f| \right),
$$
Then there exists $q>p$ and $C_1>0$ such that $f \in L^q(Q)$, with the estimate
$$
\frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q |f|^q \leq C_1 \left( \frac{1}{|Q|} \int_Q |f|^p \right)^\frac{q}{p}.
$$
The question is : what if we replace the maximal function by fractional maximal function ? Assume that there exists $p\leq n$ such that for almost every $x\in Q$,
$$
\sup_{r>0} \left( \frac{1}{ r^{n-p} } \int_{B(x,r)} |f|^p \right)^\frac{1}{p} \leq C_0 \sup_{r>0} \left( \frac{1}{r^{n-1}} \int_{B(x,r)} |f| \right),
$$
Is it true that there exists $q>p$ such that :
$$
\frac{1}{|Q|^\frac{n-q}{n} } \int_Q |f|^q \leq C_1 \left( \frac{1}{|Q|^\frac{n-p}{n} } \int_Q |f|^p \right)^\frac{q}{p}.
$$